# Scraping Google Results with Python

Tags: python

Is there a way to scrape more than 64 results from google with python without getting my IP address instantly blocked?

Comment: How do you do this? Please include your code.

Comment: Using tor could be a solution

Comment: I found this.

http://incolumitas.com/2013/01/06/googlesearch-a-rapid-python-class-to-get-search-results/

But the author claims it is not ported to 2.7 yet.

Answer (score 1):

I use tsocks and ssh-tunnels to machines with other ip addresses to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

64 result is the limit? Sounds weird to me!

Even with browser, I can navigate till the 100th page with no problem.

I'm very curious about how did you reach this limit.

Anyway: classical possible solutions are:

- proxying ( IE: tor )
- delaying requests
- randomly switch user agent